# Route [register] not defined laravel Fortify

Tags: laravel

Hola a todos una consulta, tengo la vista con el formulario para crear una cuenta de usuario (laravel forty estoy usando para el tema de Auth) pero ahora necesito incluir dicho formulario en una vista diferente y me arroja el error: Route [register] not defined.

Mi pregunta es en que parte puedo encontrar esta ruta, o mejor de que manera incluirla en mi archivo de rutas (web.php) ya que para incluirla aqui debo pasarle la clase respectiva...

Saludos a todos

Comment: Todas las rutas de laravel forty estan en: `vendor->laravel->forty->routes->routes`

Comment: Pero como te sale el error? Ya que si quieres cambiar las rutas es un paso simple, te dejo una ayuda https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/proper-way-to-override-jetstreamfortify-auth-routes

Comment: Hola @JuanRivera, gracias, estuve revisando el link pero siguiendo los pasos igual aparece el error

Comment: No se entiende si esa ruta es a la que quieres acceder para mostrar el form ( GET ) o es la ruta POST a la que quieres enviar el formulario, Ayudaría si haces un `php artisan route:list` y muestras las que tienen que ver con el registro.